# Change digit in a number java

Tags: java, arrays, string, numbers

I'm trying to do the next code: it will have a string '00000' and it will have to go until '99999', each time when one of the chars is 3 it will be changed by a 'E', and printed. For example '00003'->'0000E'

I'm trying to do a for loop, by i don't know how to do the "count" (00000,00001,00002, etc)

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps posting what code you have will help explain your problem.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would solve this.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; ++i) {
    String my_str = String.format("%05d", i);
    String my_new_str = my_str.replaceAll("3", "E");
    System.out.prinln(my_new_str);
}
```

Comment: Plus one for not mixing data and presentation.

Comment: `String my_str = String.format("%05d", i);` to keep the leading 0's in OP's example. Also, should be `i < 100000` assuming 99999 is inclusive.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Should I edit this in my answer or not? I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 2):

In all cases, maintain an integral type for the *data*:

```
for (int n = 0; n <= 99999; ++n)/*etc*/
```

1. The bodge way: convert n to a String with leading zeros using your favourite number formatter class. Replace each '3' with 'E'.
2. The cute way: implement your own number formatter and use that to display `n`.

Both approaches are more elegant than doing the actual counting on a String. Don't mix *data* and *presentation*.

Answer (score 0):

As some other replies said you should use a `for` using the `int` type for the number

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
{
   // fill the number with zeros (if needed) and then it will replace the "3" with "E"
   System.out.println(ldap(i+"").replace("3", "E")); 
}
```

and then create a `lpad` function the is used to fill the remaining space if the length is different from the one desired...

ie. you want all number long 4 digit, the number `11` has a length of 2 characters, then you will have to prepend 2 character `0`

```
public static String ldap(String prop)
{
    while(prop.length() < 4)  // continue until the length is less then 4 (or the length desired)
    {
        prop = "0"+prop;  // prepend the character '0' to the number
    }
    return prop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all '3's with 'E's

```
public static String replace3WithE(String s) {
    return ("" + s).replaceAll("3", "E");
}
```